# Compile Swift on Windows from Silver Command Line?

Tags: swift, command-line, remobjects

I've been learning Swift for a little bit now, and I really want to use it. However, compiling Swift on Windows is quite a chore. I can do it from Visual Studio 2015 easily, but VS2015 support is very poor, and incredibly hard to work with; I would prefer to use Atom and the command line. I use RemObject's Silver to compile to .NET, but I can never get the command line to work.

When I use the Elements.exe at `C:\Program Files (x86)\RemObjects Software\Elements\Bin`, passing the filename as a parameter, it tells me that `print` is undefined.

Does anyone know how to use Silver's command line to compiler Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried referencing the [online documentation](https://docs.elementscompiler.com/Compiler/CommandLineCompiler/)?

calling elements needs some libraries to import:

```
elements --mode=ECHOES --reference=Swift myfile.swift
```

Comment: I tried the command, but it tells me that the two switches you gave were invalid, so I changed the two `-`s to one, and it started, but it still tells me that print is undefined and it can't find System.Linq.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using MSBuild, rather than Elements.exe, to build Elements projects from the command line. It's more complete and supports more advanced build tasks needed for some project types.

That said, `--mode` and `--reference` should definitely work. Can you post a complete command line and output?

You will need `--reference=Swift` in order for `print()` & co to be known, and `--reference System.Core` to use LINQ.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/TZyzFoj.png) is a screenshot of CMD when I attempt to execute the command. `=` and `:` are interchangable, and when I change the single dash to the double that you said should work, I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/LGlfX3I.png). Sadly, your suggestion doesn't work... But is there a way to use MSBuild outside of Visual Studio? The whole point of me trying to use the command line is to **not** use VS...

Comment: Can you try using the latest version of Elements, 8.3? We made a lot of improvements to the command line compiler. Yes, you can use MSBuild from the command line, just type "msbuild" — no Visual Studio needed or involved.

Comment: Also, FWIW, `elements --reference=Swift foo.swift`, with two dashes, runs fine for me, and does recognize the --reference parameter...